# Setting the model in a nested route in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a nested `edit` route:

```
@resource 'dashboard.communities.community', path: ':community_id', ->
  @route 'edit'
```

In my route, I try to retrieve the model with `modelFor`:

```
CivicSourcing.DashboardCommunitiesCommunityEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend

  model: (params, queryParams, transition) ->
    @modelFor('community')
```

But this returns `undefined`. The parent route is successfully retrieving the `community`, though. Any idea what might be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're resource name is `dashboard.communities.community` not `community`

```
@modelFor('dashboard.communities.community')
```

Here's a similar example for `colors.cool`

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/442/edit

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense, actually.